# Migration of kubernetes master node from 1 server to another server

Tags: kubernetes

I have a bare metal server that houses a master Kubernetes node. I would need to move the master node to a fresh bare metal server. How can we move or migrate it?

I've done my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239979/migration-of-kubernetes-master) but most of them are related to GCP cluster where we move 4 directories from old node to new node, and also change the IP and that question was asked 5 years ago which is outdated now.

```
/var/etcd
/srv/kubernetes
/srv/sshproxy
/srv/salt-overlay
```

Whats the proper way to move it assuming we are using the most recent k8s version of 1.17

Comment: Did you try other examples like [How to move Kubernetes master node from one server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163698/how-to-move-kubernetes-master-node-from-one-server-to-another)?

Comment: @Mark yes i tried but the IP address portion I understand. The thing thats missing is what files needed to be copied and moved over to the new server. The directories mentioned in the example doesnt exist for newer version of kubernetes/bare metal clusters

Comment: Yes that is correct, but for bare metal there is still another link to to the github issue [Changing masterIP address](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-418879755) `including --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd`. At this stage you should start with etcd backub/snapshot

Comment: By the way how did you create cluster (using kubeadm?). Did you try to create etcd snapshot and recreate on the new master-node using instructions provided in the link above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#) mentioned in the comments and [IP address changes in Kubernetes Master Node](https://medium.com/@juniarto.samsudin/ip-address-changes-in-kubernetes-master-node-11527b867e88):

**1**. Verify your `etcd data directory` looking into `etcd pod in kube-system namespace`:

(default values using k8s v1.17.0 created with kubeadm),

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/etcd
      name: etcd-data
```

**2**. Preparation:

- copy `/etc/kubernetes/pki` from **Master1** to the **new Master2**:

```
    #create backup directory in Master2,
    mkdir ~/backup

    #copy from Master1 all key,crt files into the Master2 
    sudo scp -r /etc/kubernetes/pki  master2@x.x.x.x:~/backup
```

- On **Master2** remove certs with keys that have the old IP address for [apiserver and etcd cert](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/certificates/#all-certificates):

```
    ./etcd/peer.crt
    ./apiserver.crt

    rm ~/backup/pki/{apiserver.*,etcd/peer.*}
```

- move `pki directory to /etc/kubernetes`

```
 cp -r ~/backup/pki  /etc/kubernetes/
```

**3**. On **Master1** create [etcd snapshot](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#backing-up-an-etcd-cluster):

Verify your `API version`:

```
kubectl exec -it etcd-Master1 -n kube-system -- etcdctl  version

etcdctl version: 3.4.3
API version: 3.4
```

- using current **etcd pod**:

```
    kubectl exec -it etcd-master1 -n kube-system --  etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key snapshot save /var/lib/etcd/snapshot1.db
```

- using or using [**etcdctl binaries**](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/releases):

```
    ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key snapshot save /var/lib/etcd/snapshot1.db
```

**4**. Copy created snapshot from **Master1** to **Master2** backup directory:

```
scp ./snapshot1.db  master2@x.x.x.x:~/backup
```

**5**. Prepare [Kubeadm config in order to reflect **Master1** configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/):

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: x.x.x.x
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  name: master2
  taints: []     # Removing all taints from Master2 node.
---
apiServer:
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns:
  type: CoreDNS
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.17.0
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  podSubnet: 10.0.0.0/16
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {}
```

**6.** Restore snapshot:

- using `etcd:3.4.3-0` docker image:

```
    docker run --rm \
        -v $(pwd):/backup \
        -v /var/lib/etcd:/var/lib/etcd \
        --env ETCDCTL_API=3 \
        k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.3-0 \
        /bin/sh -c "etcdctl snapshot restore './snapshot1.db' ; mv /default.etcd/member/ /var/lib/etcd/"
```

- or using `etcdctl` binaries:

```
    ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 snapshot restore  './snapshot1.db' ; mv ./default.etcd/member/ /var/lib/etcd/
```

**7.** Initialize **Master2**:

```
    sudo kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd --config kubeadm-config.yaml
    # kubeadm-config.yaml prepared in 5 step.
```

- notice:

```
[WARNING DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [master2 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 master2_IP]
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [master2 localhost] and IPs [master2_ip 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [master2 localhost] and IPs [master2_ip 127.0.0.1 ::1]
.
.
.  
  Your Kubernetes control-plane has initialized successfully!
      mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
      sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
      sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

- After k8s object verification (short example):

```
    kubectl get nodes
    kubectl get pods -o wide
    kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
    systemctl status kubelet
```

- If all deployed k8s objects like pods,deployments etc, were moved into your new **Master2** node:

```
    kubectl drain Master1
    kubectl delete node Master1
```

---

> Note:
>
> In addition please consider **Creating Highly Available clusters** in this setup you should have possibility to more than 1 master, in this configuration you can  create/remove additional control plane nodes in more safely way.

- [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)
- [Tutorial](https://octetz.com/docs/2019/2019-03-26-ha-control-plane-kubeadm/)
- [Documentation Operating etcd clusters for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/)

Comment: fantastic!  way to go!!